# Locating the Temporary ASP Files for a particular Application Pool

Tags: iis, asp-classic, location, temp

I currently manage an server with more than a dozen websites with individual application pools each. I am trying to locate the Temporary ASP files for a particular Application pool, as I need to remove them for a patch that we are updating on a site.

How can I locate the particular temp files that are associated with the Application pool.

I know that the file path is C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 but I can not figure out which files are associated to which Application Pool.

Is this possible? I would prefer not to delete all the temp files.

Comment: I can't seem to determine how to absolutely match the hash folder name to the application pool. Another solution could be to change the temp directory location (then restarting the application pool) so that you can have a fresh set of logs to delete: http://forums.asp.net/t/1943868.aspx?Setting+the+attribute+tempDirectory+on+a+per+website+basis+not+working+

Comment: Are you sure this is asp-classic? Sounds more like .Net.

Comment: what IIS version you have?

Comment: IIS 8  - the Application Pool settings are .Net CLR Version v4.0.30319 and Pipeline is Integrated

Comment: Looks like you're using a .Net application, not a classic asp... the path of temporary binaries usually is C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET File\ name of application

Answer (score 1):

Use "Process Explorer" aka procexp.exe from Sysinternals

Menu View -> Select Columns...
choose "User Name"
OK

find appropriate apppool based on the "user name" column

or

Launch IIS Manager, look for feature "Worker Processes". Find process ID of appropriate apppool. Look for this process ID (PID) in the Process Explorer

Click on it

now, from Menu choose:
View -> Lower Pane View -> Handles

The list of all handles to files will be shown there. Look for files in path 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

It's easier if you sort by Path ("name" column)